# What is the convention for column-major order matrix transformations?

Tags: opengl, transformation

According to [this cheat sheet](http://antongerdelan.net/teaching/3dprog1/maths_cheat_sheet.pdf) for CG, if I want to use column-major order for my matrix/vector math I have to multiply from the left applying transformations from right to left, i.e. v' = P * V * v

I built my view and projection matrices like this

```
Matrix44 view(right.x, right.y, right.z, -position.x,
              up.x, up.y, up.z, -position.y,
             -forward.x, forward.y, forward.z, -position.z,
              0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

Matrix44 projection(Sx, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, Sy, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                    0.0f, 0.0f, Sz, Pz,
                    0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
```

However, when using them in the vertex shader

```
gl_Position = projection * view * vec4(position, 1.0);
```

I cannot see my geometry unless I swap the transformation to

```
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0) * view * projection;
```

which means that I am using row-major order instead of column order. So my question is if the pdf I'm following is correct in the notation for the column-major order for view and projection matrices or what am I missing?

Comment: Can you please link to your source pdf? Your link seems to have disappeared. It should be linked like this: `[some example pdf](http://www.example.com/example.pdf)`

Comment: Sorry, missed it. I updated the question.

Comment: I have heard that OpenGL's matrices are [always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15993339/opengl-order-of-matrix-transformations) [backwards](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/169957-Reason-why-opengl-transform-in-reverse). I don't know enough about this to make an answer, however.

Comment: in general the convention is opposite in US and in EU.
another factor depends on your programming language.
which one is the index varying the fastest (row or column) ?